# How to convert a string of text into a vector based on given values numeric values to replace each letter with

Tags: r

I have a list of strings (class: "factor") which is called ptuples in the below code:

```
aminoacid <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
aminoacid1 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
aminoacid2 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
df <- expand.grid(aminoacid, aminoacid1, aminoacid2)
df <- transform(df, newname = paste(df$Var1, df$Var2, df$Var3, sep=""))
ptuples <- df[,4]
```

I want to convert each of these strings (length 3) into a vector of length 15 by defining each amino acid (letter) with 5 numbers, as shown in this table.

```
          pah         pss         ms         cc          ec
A -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842
C -1.34267179  0.46542300 -0.8620345 -1.0200786 -0.25516894
D  1.05015062  0.30242411 -3.6559147 -0.2590236 -3.24176791
E  1.35733226 -1.45275578  1.4766610  0.1129444 -0.83715681
F -1.00610084 -0.59046634  1.8909687 -0.3966186  0.41194139
G -0.38387987  1.65201497  1.3301017  1.0449765  2.06385566
H  0.33616543 -0.41662780 -1.6733690 -1.4738898 -0.07772917
I -1.23936304 -0.54652238  2.1314349  0.3931618  0.81630366
K  1.83146558 -0.56109831  0.5332237 -0.2771101  1.64762794
L -1.01895162 -0.98693471 -1.5046185  1.2658296 -0.91181195
M -0.66312569 -1.52353917  2.2194787 -1.0047207  1.21181214
N  0.94535614  0.82846219  1.2991286 -0.1688162  0.93339498
P  0.18862522  2.08084151 -1.6283286  0.4207004 -1.39177378
Q  0.93056541 -0.17926549 -3.0048731 -0.5025910 -1.85303476
R  1.53754853 -0.05472897  1.5021086  0.4403185  2.89744417
S -0.22788299  1.39869991 -4.7596375  0.6701745 -2.64747356
T -0.03181782  0.32571153  2.2134612  0.9078985  1.31337035
V -1.33661279 -0.27854634 -0.5440132  1.2419935 -1.26225362
W -0.59533918  0.00907760  0.6719274 -2.1275244 -0.18358096
Y  0.25999617  0.82992312  3.0973596 -0.8380164  1.51150958
```

How can I convert these all of these strings into vectors of length 15? The next step is to use k-means clustering to cluster into 100 groups, so if a particular format would make that easier, I would appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output a matrix, with one row of 15 columns for each ptuple, where `key` is your 20x5 dataframe or matrix of numbers.  You should be able to use this directly in a `dist` function or similar for further clustering.

```
output <- t(sapply(as.character(ptuples),
                   function(x) sapply(1:3, function(i) key[substr(x,i,i),])))

head(output)
    [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]     [,10]      [,11]      [,12]     [,13]      [,14]    [,15]     
AAA -0.5914597 -1.302093  -0.7330651 1.570392   -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084
CAA -1.342672  0.465423   -0.8620345 -1.020079  -0.2551689 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084
DAA 1.050151   0.3024241  -3.655915  -0.2590236 -3.241768  -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084
EAA 1.357332   -1.452756  1.476661   0.1129444  -0.8371568 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084
FAA -1.006101  -0.5904663 1.890969   -0.3966186 0.4119414  -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084
GAA -0.3838799 1.652015   1.330102   1.044976   2.063856   -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084 -0.5914597 -1.302093 -0.7330651 1.570392 -0.1455084
```

Comment: Where's this object `key` you speak of? Did you perhaps copy some code from my answer and forget to include it? ;)

Comment: It is just the table I copied from the question (using `overflow::soread`), although I thought it made sense to use the same name as in your answer. I assumed the OP already had it, so didn't reproduce it again!

Comment: @AndrewGustar How would I change this if I had strings of length 5? Just change it to sapply(1:5 ... ?

Comment: @AndrewGustar Doing this gives me several NA values in the output, even though all of the characters in the input string are in the key.

Comment: @JackArnestad Interesting. I've just tried with a subset of ptuples(5) and also got that problem, though I'm not quite sure why. I did, however, solve it by dropping unused factor levels in the subset I used, so you could try `output <- t(sapply(as.character(droplevels(ptuples)),...` and see if that works.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Well, I'm not sure if I should use drop levels cause with my huge data set, I'm not sure if I'm losing some essential data when doing that. Would that be the case? Maybe I am misunderstanding what droplevels does. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JackArnestad No, when you take a subset of a factor vector, the entire list of factor levels is normally stored, whether or not they appear in the subset. `droplevels` simply drops any unused ones. It should not make a difference, and I'm not sure why it helped in this case. The other thing you could try is to avoid factors and just treat everything as `character`. `ptuples <- as.character(ptuples)`, but again this should be what happens at the start of the `sapply`. If this doesn't help you will have to find some cases that are producing `NA` and try to reproduce the problem line-by-line.

Comment: Even doing droplevels isn't working for me :( Do you have any other possible ideas? Thank you so much again!

Comment: @JackArnestad I think you will have to identify a `NA` in the output and try to work out which value of `ptuples` is causing the problem. `which(is.na(output))` will be a start, and bear in mind that these will be locations in the matrix stored as a vector, so it will take a bit of unpicking. But first, double check all of the `aminoacid` vectors and the row names of `key`, as that is the most likely source of an error. Good luck!

Comment: @JackArnestad You could also try `unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(ptuples),"")))` to see if there are any values in `ptuples` that don't appear in `key`.

Answer (score 1):

```
aminoacid <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
aminoacid1 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
aminoacid2 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
df <- expand.grid(aminoacid, aminoacid1, aminoacid2)
df <- transform(df, newname = paste(df$Var1, df$Var2, df$Var3, sep=""))
ptuples <- df[,4]

key <- read.table(text="          pah         pss         ms         cc          ec
A -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842
                  C -1.34267179  0.46542300 -0.8620345 -1.0200786 -0.25516894
                  D  1.05015062  0.30242411 -3.6559147 -0.2590236 -3.24176791
                  E  1.35733226 -1.45275578  1.4766610  0.1129444 -0.83715681
                  F -1.00610084 -0.59046634  1.8909687 -0.3966186  0.41194139
                  G -0.38387987  1.65201497  1.3301017  1.0449765  2.06385566
                  H  0.33616543 -0.41662780 -1.6733690 -1.4738898 -0.07772917
                  I -1.23936304 -0.54652238  2.1314349  0.3931618  0.81630366
                  K  1.83146558 -0.56109831  0.5332237 -0.2771101  1.64762794
                  L -1.01895162 -0.98693471 -1.5046185  1.2658296 -0.91181195
                  M -0.66312569 -1.52353917  2.2194787 -1.0047207  1.21181214
                  N  0.94535614  0.82846219  1.2991286 -0.1688162  0.93339498
                  P  0.18862522  2.08084151 -1.6283286  0.4207004 -1.39177378
                  Q  0.93056541 -0.17926549 -3.0048731 -0.5025910 -1.85303476
                  R  1.53754853 -0.05472897  1.5021086  0.4403185  2.89744417
                  S -0.22788299  1.39869991 -4.7596375  0.6701745 -2.64747356
                  T -0.03181782  0.32571153  2.2134612  0.9078985  1.31337035
                  V -1.33661279 -0.27854634 -0.5440132  1.2419935 -1.26225362
                  W -0.59533918  0.00907760  0.6719274 -2.1275244 -0.18358096
                  Y  0.25999617  0.82992312  3.0973596 -0.8380164  1.51150958")

key$letter <- row.names(key)

for(l in key$letter){
  ptuples <- gsub(l, paste(key[key$letter==l,1:5],collapse = " ", " "),ptuples)

}

 ptuples[1]
```

> [1] "-0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651 1.5703918
>   -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651 1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651 1.5703918 -0.14550842"

Depending on your needs, you might want to run this or something equivalent next to make it into a nice structured data.frame:

```
library(splitstackshape)
df <- cSplit(as.data.frame(ptuples), 'ptuples', sep=" ", type.convert=FALSE)
head(df)

    ptuples_01  ptuples_02 ptuples_03 ptuples_04  ptuples_05  ptuples_06  ptuples_07 ptuples_08 ptuples_09  ptuples_10  ptuples_11  ptuples_12 ptuples_13 ptuples_14
1: -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918
2: -1.34267179    0.465423 -0.8620345 -1.0200786 -0.25516894 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918
3:  1.05015062  0.30242411 -3.6559147 -0.2590236 -3.24176791 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918
4:  1.35733226 -1.45275578   1.476661  0.1129444 -0.83715681 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918
5: -1.00610084 -0.59046634  1.8909687 -0.3966186  0.41194139 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918
6: -0.38387987  1.65201497  1.3301017  1.0449765  2.06385566 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842 -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918
    ptuples_15
1: -0.14550842
2: -0.14550842
3: -0.14550842
4: -0.14550842
5: -0.14550842
6: -0.14550842
```