# Efficient way of replacing character string with numeric values based on data frame "dictionary"

Tags: r

This is related to this question:

[How to convert a string of text into a vector based on given values numeric values to replace each letter with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392901/how-to-convert-a-string-of-text-into-a-vector-based-on-given-values-numeric-valu/46393012?noredirect=1#comment81298003_46393012)

For ease, I will put the same information here:

```
aminoacid <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
aminoacid1 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
aminoacid2 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y")
df <- expand.grid(aminoacid, aminoacid1, aminoacid2)
df <- transform(df, newname = paste(df$Var1, df$Var2, df$Var3, sep=""))
ptuples <- df[,4]
```

I want to convert each of these strings (length 3) into a vector of length 15 by defining each amino acid (letter) with 5 numbers, as shown in this table.

```
key <-
  read.table(
    text = "          pah         pss         ms         cc          ec
    A -0.59145974 -1.30209266 -0.7330651  1.5703918 -0.14550842
    C -1.34267179  0.46542300 -0.8620345 -1.0200786 -0.25516894
    D  1.05015062  0.30242411 -3.6559147 -0.2590236 -3.24176791
    E  1.35733226 -1.45275578  1.4766610  0.1129444 -0.83715681
    F -1.00610084 -0.59046634  1.8909687 -0.3966186  0.41194139
    G -0.38387987  1.65201497  1.3301017  1.0449765  2.06385566
    H  0.33616543 -0.41662780 -1.6733690 -1.4738898 -0.07772917
    I -1.23936304 -0.54652238  2.1314349  0.3931618  0.81630366
    K  1.83146558 -0.56109831  0.5332237 -0.2771101  1.64762794
    L -1.01895162 -0.98693471 -1.5046185  1.2658296 -0.91181195
    M -0.66312569 -1.52353917  2.2194787 -1.0047207  1.21181214
    N  0.94535614  0.82846219  1.2991286 -0.1688162  0.93339498
    P  0.18862522  2.08084151 -1.6283286  0.4207004 -1.39177378
    Q  0.93056541 -0.17926549 -3.0048731 -0.5025910 -1.85303476
    R  1.53754853 -0.05472897  1.5021086  0.4403185  2.89744417
    S -0.22788299  1.39869991 -4.7596375  0.6701745 -2.64747356
    T -0.03181782  0.32571153  2.2134612  0.9078985  1.31337035
    V -1.33661279 -0.27854634 -0.5440132  1.2419935 -1.26225362
    W -0.59533918  0.00907760  0.6719274 -2.1275244 -0.18358096
    Y  0.25999617  0.82992312  3.0973596 -0.8380164  1.51150958"
  )
```

The method proposed in this post was:

```
output <- t(sapply(as.character(ptuples),
                   function(x) sapply(1:3, function(i) key[substr(x,i,i),])))
```

However, this is very inefficient and computationally heavy when working with character vectors with length 10^9

How can this be done efficiently? I was thinking something with package hashmap, but I wasn't sure how to do it. I would still like the output in a data frame like in the proposed solution above.

Thanks!

Comment: Oops, updated now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of methods that seems to be faster than the current approach.

**1)**  This method uses only a single loop and with `strsplit` splits the 'ptuples'

```
t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(ptuples), ""), function(x) c(t(key[x,])
```

**2)**  We `paste` into a single string and then do the split once and `cbind` by subsetting

```
m1 <- key[strsplit(paste(ptuples, collapse=""), "")[[1]],]

output3 <- cbind(m1[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),], m1[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),],
                m1[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),])
```

#### Benchmarks

Based on the dataset provided by OP, the `system.time` are

```
 system.time({
output <- t(sapply(as.character(ptuples),
                   function(x) sapply(1:3, function(i) key[substr(x,i,i),])))
   })
# user  system elapsed 
#   3.13    0.00    3.28 


system.time({
   output2 <- t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(ptuples), ""), function(x) c(t(key[x,]))))
    })
#user  system elapsed 
#   1.50    0.01    1.52 

system.time({
m1 <- key[strsplit(paste(ptuples, collapse=""), "")[[1]],]

output3 <- cbind(m1[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),], m1[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),],
                    m1[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),])
   })
#user  system elapsed 
#   0.01    0.00    0.02
```

Comment: For either method, if I do this is there still a way to maintain the original string in the row names of the data frame? That was one thing I was looking to keep from the original solution. Thanks!

Comment: @KeshavMotwani  That you can just assign the rownames of output2 or `output3` with `ptuples`. i.e. `row.names(output2) <- as.character(ptuples)`

Comment: For the second method, if I wanted to expand it to strings with length 5, would I do output3 <- cbind(m1[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),], m1[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),],
                m1[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSES),], m1[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),])), m1[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),])

Comment: @KeshavMotwani  You can do it with any method.  If it becomes a bit more like 10 or so, then you may have to loop it.  For 5, it would be `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)`

Comment: How would you loop it? Sorry for all the questions, you can probably tell I am still learning the basics. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @KeshavMotwani  You could do `lapply(1:3, function(i)  seq(i, length.out = 3, by = 3))`

Comment: @KeshavMotwani  I meant `do.call(cbind, lapply(1:3, function(i)  m1[seq(i, nrow(m1), by = 3),]))`

Comment: @KeshavMotwani  Please check how it works on your original dataset